# warning:root:file 'precise.tar.gz.gpg' missing

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

Firstly I tried to install the 12.04 upgrade via the update manager GUI from 11.10 after there was no more updates to install and after a fresh reboot but all that would happen is it would say downloading release upgrade tool then that it is nothing else.

So I tried running this from the terminal\command line

```
brown@brown-Ubuntu:~$ update-manager -d
brown@brown-Ubuntu:~$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  Connection failed                                                            
Get:1 Upgrade tool [5612 kB]                                                   
Fetched 5612 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
WARNING:root:file 'precise.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Can someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 3):

So I've found sorta workaround:

- Open /var/lib/update-manager/meta-release, and find strings:

> ```
> Dist: precise
> Name: Precise Pangolin
> Version: 12.04 LTS
> Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2012 12:04:00 UTC
> Supported: 1
> Description: This is the 12.04 LTS release
> Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
> ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
> ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
> UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/precise.tar.gz
> UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/precise.tar.gz.gpg
> ```

- Download UpgradeTool and UpgradeToolSignature files
- Upload them to any other web-server and modify corresponding strings (I guess that even file:/// will work)
- sudo do-release-upgrade

Worked for me, hope'll help you either. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

1. Modify the file "/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release" to replace "archive.ubuntu.com" to "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
2. Run "do-release-upgrade"
3. When it paused at "Third party sources disabled", open another ssh session to modify "/etc/apt/sources.list" and replace "archive.ubuntu.com" to "old-releases.ubuntu.com"
4. Continue to upgrade