# Upgrade 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: unity, 13.10, 14.04

I tried to upgrade to 14.04 and that came up, Not sure what to do next.

```
ruedi@ruedi-XPS-One-2710:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  Connection failed                                                            
Get:1 Upgrade tool [4,403 kB]                                                  
Fetched 4,403 kB in 6s (493 kB/s)                                              
WARNING:root:file 'trusty.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem. 
ruedi@ruedi-XPS-One-2710:~$
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

This might be duplicate for this [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125728/warningrootfile-precise-tar-gz-gpg-missing). Try the same solution posted there! Or you can simply download the media and choose update the current version from the installation menu